# Eclipse RCP Application doesn't show UI-Elements of external plugins

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm currently adapting an eclipse-plugin for an eclipse-rcp application.
The framework version wasn't changed in this progress. It's still based on eclipse 3.8. So no framework update. But somehow I'm not able to show my ui-elements in the new version.

I tried the basic sample-plugin of eclipse. It works perfectly in the old one but not in the new one.

The plugin is loaded and will be executed. The UI-Elements are loaded from the plugin.xml but somehow they are not displayed. I put the same sample file into the old one and it works perfectly. See [Old Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo10A.png) and [New Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oKcj.png)

Does eclipse rcp provide any methods to disable the ui-elements of external plugins with something like a white- or blacklist?
I'm thankful for every input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help with the support of the application I was able to resolve the problem. They implemented in the new version a permission management. I had to add an suffix to all my ids of menus, views and buttons otherwise this elements will be filtered.